# Custom keymapping in VsCodium

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard, keymapping, keymaps, vscodium

I recently changed my laptop's motherboard, and strangely, one of my keyboard keys changed its behavior (from the `?/°` key to `right control` - I'm using an ABNT2 keyboard). I tried to remap the key with SharpKeys, but unfortunately, that didn't work (I didn't find the key and don't know the code related to that key).

Anyway, although I didn't manage to make it, I would like to at least add a keymap in VsCodium to remap this key, is it possible?